# Write protractor test case

Tags: angularjs, protractor

i need to write protractor test script for sign in button. I need to write test script for this particular code.

```
<a class="mob-btn ng-scope" 
   ng-if="!isLoggedIn()" 
   translate="landing.text.signin" 
   `ui`-sref="login" 
    href="/login">
 Sign In</a>
```

Comment: Please tell us what's your problem?  Fail to find / click the button?

Comment: found the answer